# How can I use Vue-Draggable-Next to get nested draggable components to work?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, draggable, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I am working with a project that needs to render a few draggable graphs on a page, but also one of those graphs also needs nested draggability inside itself. I figured it would be a pretty simple case of having each of the graphs be a separate component and then just render those graphs on the page. However, the one that needs the nested draggability doesn't work as I would like.

I've seen a few posts doing something similar with people using `<nested-draggable>` tags, but I'm pretty sure this won't work in my case due to not using the same data structure. The examples I've seen are using nested arrays or objects. [EXAMPLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53307959/nested-vue-draggable-elements)

I am capturing a click event on all of the children elements inside of the wrapped component, but they are immobile. I've also raised the z-index of the child component, but that doesn't seem to have an effect either.

All of the graphs/charts are on the **App.vue** page and wrapped with the `<draggable>` tag.  **Chart1.vue** is the parent component for **Chart3.vue** which also has elements wrapped in the `<draggable>` tag, but obviously is not working.

Is there something I am missing or perhaps a better way to go about my code here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

**CodeSandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-khayyam-vixsh?file=/src/components/Chart3.vue

Comment: For dynamic element with `v-for`, try using `v-model` or `list` props instead. See [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-chatelet-yqcdj?file=/src/components/Chart3.vue)

Comment: This is brilliant! Cheers!